# Operador "!=" não funciona no meu código?

Tags: c#, .net, array, operadores

Tenho uma parte do meu programa que faço várias verificações quando o botão é clicado e uma dessa verificações é: ele pega o valor inserido no `textboxRankTecnica` e tem de comprar com a *array* `ranksAceitaveis`. Se ele inserir um valor que não está em `ranksAceitaveis`, ele tem de exibir o `MessageBox`. Se for igual, ele continua com o código, mas o grande problema é que mesmo digitando um valor aceitável, ele lança o `textbox`. Códigos que já tentei (nenhum deles fez o que queria, pois mesmo digitando um valor correto, ele retorna a mensagem):

```
string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+", "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++" };
        else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (ranksAceitaveis.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (!textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Contains(ranksAceitaveis[i]))
                {
                    passouCriacao = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("O Rank digitado é inválido [...]".", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    break;
                }
            }


        }

    /*outro codigo:*/ string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+" , "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++"};

    else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != ranksAceitaveis.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            passouCriacao = false;
            MessageBox.Show("O Rank inserido é inválido, digite um [...]".", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    /*outro codigo:*/ else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != "E".ToLowerInvariant() || textBoxRankTecnica.Text != "E+".ToLowerInvariant()) //E o resto das verificações

    /*outro codigo:*/ else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (ranksAceitaveis.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != ranksAceitaveis[i].ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    passouCriacao = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Text [...]".", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }   
        }
```

Comment: É isto que deseja? https://dotnetfiddle.net/5sJWKh

Comment: Também não foi para o meu caso. Mesmo que eu insira um valor correto (os que estão na variável "ranksAceitaveis") ele continua com o mesmo erro. Tá chato isso, hein e.e. Não sei o porquê de nenhum código destes ter funcionado até agora ^^. Mas mesmo assim, obrigado por tentar ajudar.

Comment: Provavelmente porque você não sabe como obter o que deseja. Sua pergunta só tem uns códigos jogados, fica difícil ajudar assim, você precisa definit o que deve acontecer com clareza antes de mais nada. E mais, tomando por base os códigos que postou que foram escritos quase aleatoriamente alguma coisa me diz que não funcionou para você porque modificou alguma coisa que não deveria. O problema só não está bem explicado. Este postados não tinham a menor chance de funcionar porque  eles não fazem sentido. Se você não entender o que está fazendo não conseguirá programar nada.

Comment: "Códigos jogados" acredito que da forma que escrevi gerou isso. Eles não são códigos jogados, são tentativas. /*outro codigo*/ significa que é outra tentativa, observe na pergunta que tem "códigos que já tentei". A intenção era dividir cada tentativa em um bloco separado, não consegui, então fiz por comentário. Talvez eu já tenha ideia do que pode estar acontecendo e tentarei solucionar.

Comment: Peguei a sua ideia como base e a adaptei para as minhas necessidades e funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que deseja verificar se o valor digitado no textbox está dentro do array, correto?

Experimente algo assim:

```
string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+", "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++" };
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxRankTecnica.Text) && ranksAceitaveis.Contains(textBoxRankTecnica.Text.ToUpper()))
{
    ...
}
```

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 2):

A pergunta não estava tão clara, o algoritmo estava bem errado, mas como o autor resolveu o problema baseado no comentário, postei como resposta.

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var textBoxRankTecnica = "C+";
        string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+", "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++" };
        for (int i = 0; i < ranksAceitaveis.Length; i++) {
            if (textBoxRankTecnica == ranksAceitaveis[i]) {
                WriteLine("O Rank digitado é válido");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xs5mf1). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gGDCDX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/RankinArray.cs).

Poderia ter sido feito com [`foreach`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas mantive a linha usada originalmente.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que não tem nada de errado, mas a cor verde mostra que a maior parte do código virou uma string.

```cs
string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+", "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++" };
        else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (ranksAceitaveis.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (!textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Contains(ranksAceitaveis[i]))
                {
                    passouCriacao = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("O Rank digitado é inválido [...]".", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    break;
                }
            }


        }

    /*outro codigo:*/ string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+" , "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++"};

    else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != ranksAceitaveis.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            passouCriacao = false;
            MessageBox.Show("O Rank inserido é inválido, digite um [...]".", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    /*outro codigo:*/ else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != "E".ToLowerInvariant() || textBoxRankTecnica.Text != "E+".ToLowerInvariant()) //E o resto das verificações

    /*outro codigo:*/ else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (ranksAceitaveis.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != ranksAceitaveis[i].ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    passouCriacao = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("Text [...]".", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }   
        }
```

Sem querer (ou sem cabeça(sem ofença)) Você colocou outra aspas depois do primeiro parenteses, na linha 9. Este é o código correto:

```cs
string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+", "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++" };
        else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (ranksAceitaveis.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (!textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Contains(ranksAceitaveis[i]))
                {
                    passouCriacao = false;
                    MessageBox.Show("O Rank digitado é inválido [...].", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    break;
                }
            }


        }

    string[] ranksAceitaveis = new string[] { "E", "E+", "D", "D+", "C", "C+" , "B", "B+", "A", "A+", "S", "S+", "S++"};

    else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != ranksAceitaveis.ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
        {
            passouCriacao = false;
            MessageBox.Show("O Rank inserido é inválido, digite um [...].", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }

    else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != "E".ToLowerInvariant() || textBoxRankTecnica.Text != "E+".ToLowerInvariant()) //E o resto das verificações

    else if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= (ranksAceitaveis.Length - 1); i++)
            {
                if (textBoxRankTecnica.Text != ranksAceitaveis[i].ToString().ToLowerInvariant())
                {
                    passouCriacao = false;
                    MessageBox.Show(Text "[...].", "Rank inválido", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }   
        }
```

Tive que tirar os comentários.